# why vector arguments not work in setColumnWidth {xlsx} ? [R]

Tags: r, xlsx

Hi I'm using package `{xlsx}` to write things in excel files, and using `setColumnWidth` to control the column width. It doesn't work when I tried to use vectors to indicate the column index and the column width

```
wb = createWorkbook()

sheet1 = createSheet(wb, sheetName = "test1")
sheet2 = createSheet(wb, sheetName = "test2")

setColumnWidth(sheet1, 1, 20)        
setColumnWidth(sheet2, 2:5, rep(20, 4)) 
# Error in .jcall(sheet, "V", "setColumnWidth", as.integer(ic), as.integer(colWidth *  : 
#         method setColumnWidth with signature (I[I)V not found

saveWorkbook(wb, 'test.xlsx')
```

Somebody know how to fix this? Let me know please. Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were actually very close! All you need to do is replace

```
setColumnWidth(sheet2, 2:5, rep(20, 4))
```

With the more explicitly declared

```
setColumnWidth(sheet2, colIndex=c(2:5), colWidth=20)
```

This way, R knows that your second argument is for the columns indexed 2 through 5. The third argument then just applies to all four of those columns.

Just remember also to use c() when you're combining multiple elements together, as in the second argument of your setColumnWidth function.